# Video compression process taking long processing time

Tags: telegram, whatsapp

Hello every one i am looking for the video compression (like whats'up /Telegram).After lot off R&d  i got ffmpeg & videocodec like library but both library taking long compression time now I am doing video compression successfully for all version but it is very time consuming process its taking almost ~30 second for 1Mb .Please if any have idea (about library or Algorithm ) how we do compression fast like what'up in less time
Thanku

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapresetandtune) argument to specific to `veryfast`.

Comment: thanks @sean , i did try for veryfast and ultrfast but its not working its taking same processing time